# Is there a way to check which pdf strategy FSCrawler will use?

Tags: fscrawler

I am using FSCrawler's REST feature to scan PDFs as they are uploaded. I'm currently using the `ocr_and_text` pdf strategy, however ocr takes too long for the user to wait for a response. I would like to send the pdf to fscrawler synchronously to use text extraction and if this doesn't work, send to an asynchronous background task for ocr.

Is there a way to do this with FSCrawler? Or is there a way to have multiple pdf strategies?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to change the pdf_strategy to `auto`.